# Check nullable type with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method which takes nullable DateTime type **effectiveDate** as a parameter.

```
List<Scales> GetScales(scales scaleId, DateTime? effectiveDate, int count)
{
    return scales.Where(rs => rs.ScaleID != scaleId)
                 .Where(rs => rs.Review.ReleaseDate >= effectiveDate)
                 .OrderByDescending(rs => rs.Review.ReleaseDate)
                 .Take(count)
                 .ToList();
}
```

This method returns a list. What I am trying to do is, if **effectiveDate** is null then it will not check `.Where(rs => rs.Review.ReleaseDate >= effectiveDate)` condition.

I can easily achieve this by a `IF..ELSE` condition. But I wanted to know, is it possible in a single LINQ statement ?

Comment: Is this Entity Framework? LINQ to Objects? Something else?

Comment: And what is scales? The one with lowercase start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to include all entries without effective date:

```
.Where(rs => !effectiveDate.HasValue || rs.Review.ReleaseDate >= effectiveDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) to do if-else checks.

But in your case, just use the fact that conditions that are chained with `&&` or `||` will be evaluated from left to right, and evaluation of the condition is stopped after a truth value can be assigned. For the OR operator `||` this means that the condition is met either if the first criteria is `true` or the first is `false` and the second is `true`:

```
.Where(rs => !effectiveDate.HasValue || rs.Review.ReleaseDate >= effectiveDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you make it a compound condition saying

```
.Where(rs => effectiveDate.HasValue && rs.Review.ReleaseDate >= effectiveDate)
```

Comment: it will be better if you  invert the order  effectiveDate.HasValue &&

Comment: Shouldn't the has value check be first? that way the greater than or equals is only executed if there's a value to execute on.

Answer (score -1):

I just check this code and its works for me.

```
.Where(rs =>effectiveDate.HasValue? rs.Review.ReleaseDat>=effectiveDate.Value:true)
```